# Pronunciation of name "Matei" by native German speakers

Tags: pronunciation, person-names, phonetics

We are considering naming our son "Matei", however as we live in a German-speaking country, we worry that native speakers of German would pronounce it /ma'tai/, different from the name's correct pronunciation in its original language (Romanian), which is /ma'tei/. My guess is the latter will be favoured only by those who've heard the name before, but those who haven't would tend to pronounce it in the former way.

I [know](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/967/how-can-i-create-a-poll-as-part-of-a-question-in-stackexchange) StackExchange sites are not primarily meant for opinion polling; however, I wonder if in comments to this question, people (ideally those who are native German speakers) could express whether their first impulse in pronouncing this name would be one or the other of the above options.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I didn't know the name and its origin. Intuitively, I would have pronounced it /ma'tai/, just as you expected.

Comment: There is nothing you or your son could ever do to completely prevent mispronounciation. Some will butcher it at first try. However, most people will stop mispronouncing once they hear how you or you son pronounce it. Von daher: Nur Mut! (I do know [ma'tei].)

Comment: Please vote up this comment if you'd pronounce this name as:  /ma`tei/

Comment: And please vote up _this_ comment if you'd pronounce this name as:  /ma`tai/

Comment: Thank you @starrin!

Comment: If I hadn't had a class mate with that name, I'd chose ma`tai, but his was also pronounced ma'tei. Yet don't worry about wrong pronounciation. It will happen, sure. But then correct it. And those who are not a buthole will pickup the real pronounciaton. Changing the spelling to suit pronounciation IMHO is not a desirable option either (though I know people who did so during emigration).

Comment: I would definitely pronounce it as ma-te-i; perhaps due to the similarity with the name Matthäus, and because I have a Brazilian friend Mateus.

Comment: It's a perennial problem for people from immigrant families to have their names mangled by the natives. Germany does have it's share of foreign nationals, so I can't imagine it would be a huge issue. Keep in mind though that while some areas are more cosmopolitan than others. In any case, I'm thinking the question is off-topic for the site, and seems to have been answered well enough already in the comments.

Comment: The language buffs at German SE are probably not the most representative group to ask though. https://xkcd.com/2618/ :-)

Comment: Haha, true! But as the minipoll above shows, even the language buffs over at German SE tend to mispronounce the name, which is what I expected/feared

Answer (score 1):

As a German native speaker, with naive reading of a name "Matei", I would pronounce it /'matai/, with stress on the first syllable.

As a part-time resident of South Eastern Europe I know the name, though, and I would pronounce it correctly, i.e. closer to its Romanian pronunciation with stress on the second syllable, and a clearer "e"-shaped dipthonge "ei" (as opposed to "ai"). I heard the name also in neighbouring Bulgaria (Матей).

Note that in Germany there is a family name "Mattey" in Germany (spelling varies) pronounced /'matai/.

The standard (= most frequent, traditional) form of this name in German is Matthias, the regional derivative of biblical Matthäus.